# How to resolve warning "Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index" while using a dataframe to create a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a code to analyze some data where I am removing rows with a null value in a certain column. It works perfectly fine and I am getting the desired results but this warning keeps flashing.

Here's part of the code that's giving the error

```
original_df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')

age_wrangled_df = original_df[pd.notnull(original_df['Age'])]

embark_wrangled_df = age_wrangled_df[pd.notnull(original_df['Embarked'])]
```

The error I keep getting is

```
C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\Codes folium\titanic.py:14: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  embark_wrangled_df = age_wrangled_df[pd.notnull(original_df['Embarked'])]
```

I have read other answers regarding this error but none helped resolve the warning. What does the error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: That's not an error.  It's a warning.  Ignore it if you don't care.

Comment: Yes but what am I doing wrong to get a warning? Everything looks fine and works fine

Comment: You are indexing with a column that is a different size than the df you are indexing.  `age_wrangled_df` is larger than `original_df`.  Perhaps you meant to say `age_wrangled_df[pd.notnull(age_wrangled_df['Embarked'])]`?